# Xcode version of Visual Studio immediate window?

Tags: xcode, unit-testing

What I'd like to do sometimes is simply call a function with some test parameters (and see the returned result) without having to compile the whole app, or put it into debug mode and set breakpoints etc. Is that possible in any way?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Swift, a Playground is often used for this purpose. Otherwise, a unit test (as implied by your tag) is exactly the way to go. You do have to compile the app, but only once; after that, you can just play around with the test. The test does have to launch the app in order to run, but that's not particularly onerous.

Answer (score 0):

From Visual Studio 2017 or from lates version, please press **Ctrl+Alt+I** 
Lets say you have a function like,

```
static int Sum(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }
```

Now write in Immediate window as following, 
?Sum(5,5);  
Now press enter.

Comment: Thanks, but I was asking if there was a way to do something like this in Xcode